# strange cache issue with HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

We have a web app that calls a url of an outside search provider to load search results.  Each time our page is hit it can pass in a current page number.  This page number is included in the url sent to the 3rd party.  I've noticed that while they report 45 pages of results, if I go to one of the pages that includes their results and then try to navigate to another page that has additional results from them, the same results from the first page are loaded.

I tried setting up my HttpWebRequest object to disable caching but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.  And, considering the url changes each time due to the page number, I wouldn't think that it would really be a cache issue.  But here's where it gets interesting.

If I copy the url that I'm retrieving in code and paste it into chrome it loads the correct results.  I then refresh the web app page and it too now loads the results for that page.  This makes no sense to me.  The code is running locally but since it's running within asp.net, it isn't using chrome to create the web request, so why does this happen?

Here's the code I have that calls the url and returns the result.

```
public static string FetchPage(string url)
{
    //Specify the encoding
    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

    HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default); ;

    //Create the http request
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

    //Create the http response from the http request
    var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    //Get the response stream
    var responseStream = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

    //Read the response stream
    string htmlStream = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

    //Close the web response
    httpWebResponse.Close();

    //Close the response stream
    responseStream.Close();

    return htmlStream;
}
```

Comment: The method by itself looks OK, what url are you passing to it to fetch the results. BTW: if you are passing different urls (i.e. your page number is part of url) than you don't have to worry about caching in any case. If you are **NOT** passing page number in your url how do you expect the called service to know which page you are requesting? If your url **DOES** change-make sure that it does, than try querying the service directly via browser or telnet. And make sure to read service provide docs/specifications - they may be expecting some other values/variables when you request specific page

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  The page number DOES change in each url so that's why I initially figured caching wouldn't be an issue.  And as I said, I've already tried querying the service directly and when I do that and then refresh my web app page that calls the same url, at that point the results DO change.  It doesn't make any sense.  The 3rd party has confirmed my url parameters are correct to their specs, so I'm really puzzled here.

Comment: I know that it should not affect anything, but considering what and how you describe your problem, did you check your IE (because you are running asp.net) internet options caching settings? If they are set to Automatic (I think that was a default for Winz IE) than reset them to "Every visit..." And make sure that your .net framework is up-to-date, it was always buggy...  Trying to make sense of Winz functionality was always difficult - AFAIR IE is using the same temp internet folders as chrome, this may explain why .net (via IE) is finding cached data to display

Comment: The issue only came to light in chrome when viewing the web app live.  So the browser was running on a completely different machine than the app.  I've even set up the results page to include no cache headers... but no luck.

Comment: As I understood your problem so far:  
1) you send a request to search service from your app (code provided) running on PC1 connecting to internet directly (**not** via proxy) -> resultset contains page1 of results  
2) you send next request from same app/same PC1 to get page2 of results specifying page number in url -> resultset contains page1 of results [instead of page2]   
3) you send request specifying url from step 2) above using Chrome browser on PC2 connecting to internet directly (**not** via proxy) -> resultset contains **page2** of results   
4) rerunning step 2) now succeeds   
???

Comment: Close, but no.  If I run step 1 and 2 locally (pc2) instead of on pc1 and then step 3 (on pc1 - everything on pc1), then I run step 2 on pc1 it then shows the correct results.  I never get the correct results on pc2 (the app server, not my local box).

Answer (score 0):

Please try these following lines to set no-cache in both `HttpWebRequest` and `WebResponse`

**For Request**

```cs
Request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store");
Request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

**For Response**

```cs
Response.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
```